# Can't understand how equation was arrived at in method of characteristics?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Say $u(x,y)$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ and suppose we have the following pde -

$u_x - u_y = u$

This equation has the following characteristics -

$\frac{dx}{1} = \frac{dy}{-1}$

$\frac{du}{dx} = u$

In my notes it says that these characteristics lead to the following equations -

$y = -x + c_1$

$u = c_2e^x$

Why is $u = c_2e^x$?? Shouldn't it be $u = f(y)e^x$?

Comment: It should be $u=f(y_0)e^{x}$, where $y_0$ is your initial condition on $y(x)$ (i.e. your $c_1$). The general solution is $u = f(y + x)e^{x}$.

Comment: You say it should be $f(y_0)e^x$...that seems like you are fixing a value for $y$. Whereas $\frac{du}{dx} = u$ does not impose any constraints on $y$, ie If $u = f(y)e^x$ then $\frac{du}{dx} = u$ will be satisfied.

Comment: Sure, if you think it should be $u = f(y)e^{x} = f(c_1 - x)e^{x}$ then take derivatives and see if you recover your PDE (you won't).

Comment: So is there a formal reason why that is the case..ie, why we get to fix a particular $y_0$ even though it 'looks like' it should be satisfied for any $y$?

Comment: An explanation in the comments section wouldn't do it justice and I'm about to go to sleep. See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LpHqrlrU5pM) for a good video explanation.

Comment: It depends on what initial data you're given. In the extreme case where it is characteristic, the problem is ill-posed.